# Lookup a specific IP address entered by form

Tags: php, forms, api, ip, lookup

I have a script that use api to get ip informations of an ip address. When a visitor enter it only shows the default informations about visitor ip, but I want to make a form so the visitor can lookup a specific IP address, by entering the IP in the form
and click lookup.

I don't know how to make it, and I need your help and thank you

index.php

```
<?php

require_once('ipapi.class.php');

$ip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = IPAPI::query("$rip");

echo "\t IP Information: " .$rip. "<br />";
echo "\t ISP: " .$query->isp . "<br />";
echo "\t Organization: " .$query->org . "<br />";
echo "\t City: " .$query->city . "<br />";
echo "\t Region: " .$query->regionName . "<br />";
echo "\t Country: " .$query->country . "<br />"; 

?>
```

Comment: sorry i didn't understand !!?

Comment: remote address is $ip, but you query $rip, which shouldn't be in quotes either, so i assume its defaulting to local

Comment: yes you right but it works perfect, i just need the form so the visitor can tape the ip he wants and get informations, sorry my english is poor :P and i hope you undsertand what i'm trying to say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an html form for that.
Your index.php should look like this:

```
<?php

require_once('ipapi.class.php');

if(isset($_GET['ip']))
    $rip = $_GET['ip'];
else
    $rip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query

$query = IPAPI::query("$rip");

echo "\t IP Information: " .$rip. "<br />";
echo "\t ISP: " .$query->isp . "<br />";
echo "\t Organization: " .$query->org . "<br />";
echo "\t City: " .$query->city . "<br />";
echo "\t Region: " .$query->regionName . "<br />";
echo "\t Country: " .$query->country . "<br />"; 

?>

<form name="input" action="#" method="get">
IP: <input type="text" name="ip">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I think that you'd a mistake within the $ip variable, so i changed to $rip.

Comment: thank you so much nirock, you are genius hihi :P it works very well,

Comment: Then, you can tick my answer as the right answer.
so other people will be able to know the right answer too...

Comment: done :) !! what if i puted this form in my home page and when you click submit, the resulat apear in other page name it lookup.php ?? what i have to do?

Comment: just change <form name="input" action="#" method="get"> to <form name="input" action="lookup.php" method="get">

Comment: thank you so much for helping me, i really appreciate that, i'm just trying to learn php, first when i change it to <form name="input" action="lookup.php" method="get"> it didn't work untill i change it too <form name="input" action="lookup_ip.php?ip=" method="get">

Comment: the file "lookup.php" is "lookup_ip.php" in your computer/server. i don't think that you need the additional ?ip=

Comment: lol you will laugh so hard when i tell you my file already was lookup_ip.php not lookup.php believe me you are dealing with a stupid man lol, i'm really happy and thankful for your time and your interest :) now everythings works fine,